# Binding to a derived property without proxy object in WPF MVVM

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

Let's say I have a domain model like:

```
class User  {
    public string FirstName  { get; set; }
    public string LastName   { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public int    Age        { get; set; }
    // tons of other stuff
}
```

I have an `ObservableCollection` of these called `UserList`, which I bind to a DataGrid like this:

```
<dg:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UserList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=Selecteduser}">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <dg:DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Path=Age, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Now I decide to add a grid column for the user's full name. My `User` object doesn't have this property, but it's easily computed if you pass me a `User` object. How can I bind to such a derived "property" on my `User` object, without creating a proxy class (aka view model) for `User` and rewriting tons of code to deal with this proxy, copy state from domain objects to proxy objects, etc.?

A rather clean and obvious solution would be an extension method, but apparently you can't bind to that.

I just want to be able to tell the grid: *for this column, pass me a User and some key indicating what this is for (e.g. "fullname"), and I'll pass you back the data to use for the column.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could certainly create most of those derived properties by multi-bindings like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="FullName">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}}">
            <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
            <Binding Path="LastName"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

For more complex things you might have to bind directly to the User object and use a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) with a converter parameter that creates the derived values:

```
public class UserConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        User user = (User)value;
        string result = string.Empty;

        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "FullName":
                result = string.Format("{0} {1}", user.FirstName, user.LastName);
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then bind like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="FullName"
    Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource UserConverter}, ConverterParameter=FullName}"/>
```

Comment: The `MultiBinding StringFormat` is perfect for my example case by not for my actual case (which is more than string formatting), but that's good to know about. However, IValueConverter is exactly what the doctor ordered. :)  Something any WPF programmer probably already knows, but I'm muddling through in an unfamiliar code base. I figured something like that must exist, but didn't know what it would look like. My googling yesterday led me to `IValueConverter`, but I was missing the binding string. Thanks. :)